# Копирование слова между двумя определёнными символами

Tags: java

Можно-ли как нибудь сделать так чтобы допустим из текста:

> мальчик сказал "привет"
>   слово в кавычках поместить в строку say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно.

Решение *в лоб*:

```
String str = "мальчик сказал \"привет\"";

int p1 = str.indexOf("\"") + 1;
int p2 = str.indexOf("\"", p1);

String say = str.substring(p1, p2);
```

Здесь в строке `str` происходит поиск позиции первой кавычки, затем происходит поиск позиции кавычки после первой найденной кавычки.

Затем, с помощью метода `String.substring(...)` происходит получение необходимой подстроки из строки `str`.

Comment: спасибо!буду знать!